# Create record based on JSON from external system

Tags: json, callout

Please hint me how to implement the following.
The external system sends a JSON file containing information about the custom object to SF. I need to create records based on this JSON file.
What do I need to configure for this?
What classes should be created and how will the authorization of this request for record creation in SF be determined?
Thanks.

I found how it works from workbench but here we didt use any autorization during request
https://www.salesforcehut.com/2019/11/multiple-records-parsing-from-json-to.html

Comment: Start at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices) if you are new to building Apex services. But it's better if you use the native REST API - no code.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has a number of options for importing records, in JSON, XML, and CSV formats, without any need to involve Apex code and the limitations that produces. You can find examples of this in the [Bulk 2.0 API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/) and [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/), particularly the Graph and Composite resources you'll find the in latter.

Authentication itself has a number of options, including [JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) and other [OAuth Authentication Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5), [SSO](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_login/identity_login_sso), or you can even use the older XML-based SOAP [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) if you prefer.

In summary, there's many different ways to accomplish your goals, but it really depends on the capabilities of the external system. Workbench itself uses an OAuth flow for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to create a rest resource. See the developer guide for how to do that. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm
The second part of that guide also describes what you can do for autorization.

Instead of writing a parser yourself like that blogpost I'd probably use a tool like [csv2apex](https://csv2apex.herokuapp.com/) to generate the parser for me though. That would provide you with apex objects that you can then transform to SObjects as needed.

Comment: For JSON, [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) works well, too.

Comment: I know it, but json2apex has quite a lot of drawbacks compared to csv2apex. It doesn't recognize object reuse very well, if your input json has a null value it won't be able to determine the type. Plus csv2apex also generates code to create json from your objects if you ever need to send a response back.